# How to do frame-by-frame animation on Android?

Tags: android, animation, mobile, png

I am trying to find out how to do png frame-by-frame animation at a good frame rate...

I have a bunch of pngs(probably 1500 png poses) and I need to play them one-by-one (just like a talking app, take tom cat as an example)

I`ve already tried SurfaceView, normal View, AnimationDrawable and also ImageView(with a thread setting the background with a sleep(33)[for a 30fps]), but none of these ways made a good frame rate compared to tom cat on bad CPU phones (like HTC Desire A).

Its also good to say that I've already added Options to set up the in SampleSize for the images, in case it needs more memory or processing speed.

I think the unique way is loading up an amount of pngs , draw on the SurfaceView and while it plays load more pngs and recycle the other bitmaps...

Anyone can help me with that? At least with some code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here you go... try this... :)
create an XML file like this on ur values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="frames">
    <item>@drawable/pak1_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/pak1_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/pak1_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/pak1_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/pak1_5</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

Now try this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           Resources res = getResources();
           TypedArray FrameImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.frames);
           animation = new AnimationDrawable();
           for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
               Drawable drawable = FrameImages.getDrawable(i);
               animation.addFrame(drawable, 33);
           }
           animation.setOneShot(false);
           ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
           imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
           // run the start() method later on the UI thread
           imageAnim.post(new Starter());
       }

       class Starter implements Runnable {
           public void run() {
               animation.start();        
           }
       }
```

Comment: well, ive already used the AnimationDrawable...its slow when you add one background image below the ImageView, also it overflows the memory, because of too many pngs...

Comment: And, this strategy crashes after 30 frames. i,e. 30 items in animation-list